# MySQL Convert String To Date Calculate Age And Order BY Age

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a mysql query that will convert a string to a date and then calculate an age and then count the ages and group by age.

I have the string to date and calculate age query:

```
SELECT YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(STR_TO_DATE( birthday,  '%m/%d/%Y' )) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < RIGHT(STR_TO_DATE( birthday,  '%m/%d/%Y' ), 5)) as age 
  FROM `persons`
```

But I can't count and group by age. Could anyone help me?

Comment: http://ma.tt/2003/12/calculate-age-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y'))))) + 0 age,
        COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM    tableNAme
GROUP   BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM (FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y'))))) + 0
ORDER   BY TotalCount DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac801/1)