# PHP and Mysql get age from birthdate stored as varchar

Tags: php, mysql, varchar

I am creating an application that takes the data from Excel file and stores in MySQL database. Then users can search through candidates based on experience, age, skills etc etc.

My table has the following structure, Name,Surname, Birthdate (stored as varchar), skills, gender, etc etc

What i need is how to compute/figure out/extract the age of the candidates using php/sql?

I am using a drop downlist with following options

```
<option value="0">--</option>
<option value="eqolderthan20">Equal or older than 20</option>  
<option value="equaloryoungerthan30">Equal or younger than 30</option>  
<option value="olderthan30">Older than 30</option>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not very clear. How is the above `<option>` related to your _Birthdate_?

Comment: Well, for example if the user chooses from the option list the candidate should be "equal or older than 20 years" then i should search in my database for candidates that are equal or older than 20 years.

Comment: Why are you using varchar to store a birthdate?

Comment: I am using Phpexcel library to read datas from Excel file, i couldn't figure out how to store it as date type in mysql. It doesn't store in the database as such. Is there any way to convert to date type from varchar and then compare it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strtotime()` to get the birthday as a timestamp, then calculate the years based on the difference from the current timestamp. Assuming `$birthday` is the varchar from your database:

```
$age_in_years = floor((time() - strtotime($birthday))/(60*60*24*365));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how should i include this into SQL to get the user based on younger or older age (for example younger than 30)?

Comment: MySQL has similar functionality to extract date information from a varchar. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706289/mysql-convert-varchar-to-date) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010382/mysql-convert-string-to-date-calculate-age-and-order-by-age)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark M. But i am struggling a bit. Suppose that this one works like a charm                                              SELECT  EXTRACT(YEAR(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),STR_TO_DATE(birthday, '%m/%d/%Y'))))) + 0 age and it extracts the age of users. But i don't want to select the ages i just want to select all infos of the users with the age of let's say younger than 30. Where should i put this Extract function

Comment: You would put that into the WHERE clause... `SELECT cols FROM table WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR(FROM...)))))+0 < 30 `